# "Неуказанный" или "не указанный"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

*...однако на не( )указанный банковский счет поступили средства.*

Answer (score 1):

В Большом толковом словаре у слова "неуказанный" значения: "недозволенный" и "неназначенный" (*в неуказанное время*). Причастие "не указанный" имеет иное значение - тот, который не был указан (например, в договоре).

Но я очень сомневаюсь, что такая фраза вообще может появиться в деловой переписке, так как смысл ее неочевиден. Обязательно будет уточнение, например, "не указанный в заявлении".